# Audacious with shortcuts in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, audacious

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and audacious as audio player.I am using a lenovo G460 notebook.It has keys which can play music.They work with Amarok. But , I want to make them work with Audacious.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You just need go to `File -> Preferences` then navigate to `Plugins -> General` and check both `Global Hotkey` and `Gnome Shortcuts`.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: is there a similar way to achieve the same for Amorok?

Comment: @DERIIIFranz You can find answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56321/how-to-bind-play-pause-key-to-amarok

Comment: I wonder where are these plugins in Audacious 4 (which uses Qt 5).

Comment: @pevik I think you need to install plugins separately on version 4

Comment: @MadukaJayalath that plugin was packaged (in Debian package) for version 3. I guess it's not compatible with version 4, otherwise it'd be packaged.

Comment: @pevik Have a look on their download page, they said they have separated it for two, https://audacious-media-player.org/download

Comment: @MadukaJayalath yes, there are 2 files to download, but that's not the problem. Looking into [git](https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious-plugins/tree/master/src) repository, hotkey plugin has not been ported to QT (ported plugins have `-qt` suffix). Debian uses still GTK port for 4.0, therefore there is `hotkey.so` plugin in [audacious-plugins](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/audacious-plugins/filelist) package. But [openSUSE already builds QT](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/multimedia:apps/audacious/audacious.changes?expand=1) thus plugin is not available.

Comment: Ah, there is already ongoing progress :) https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious-plugins/pull/86

Comment: FYI plugin got merged into master: https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious-plugins/commit/975021930b8a75fcfb12edd547c1e13f41db65ed

Comment: Compiled and loaded manually. Works perfectly, it even remember my settings from GTK.