# Multimediakeys don't work after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.04

I updated my ubuntu to 14.04 (from a 13.10). After the update, my multimediakeys (next, play/pause, prev, mute, vol up, vol down) don't work.

I'm on a dell latitude.

**Edit**: worked fine after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced same issue in Amarok.

In my case only play/pause key not working. The problem is in the system wide global shortcuts. I've assign another keys combination under Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts for the "Play (or play/pause)" key

And then play/pause key starts working in Amarok.

Make sure global shortcut for Amarok has been assigned (see how: [How to bind play/pause key to Amarok?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56321/how-to-bind-play-pause-key-to-amarok))